# Обновление контента на сайте взависимости от добавления информации в базу данных

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Я программирую уже несколько лет, однако не сталкивался с реализацией обновления какого-либо контента на сайте по причине обновления информации в БД. К примеру, могу привести, сообщения Вконтакте. Другой человек написал сообщение, по сути оно добавилось в БД и у меня без обновления страницы оно появилось. Я понимаю это, как создание "слушателя" на клиенте, и посыл запроса при обновлении БД с сервера. 
Вопрос в том, как такие действия реализуются? 
Если я сложно объясняю приведу еще пример: я нахожусь в админпанели интернет магазина и получаю уведомление о поступлении заказа.

Прошу сказать как это называется, чтобы я мог "прогуглить" этот вопрос, или же привести пример простейшей реализации.

Использую Mysql, планирую реализовывать на php, Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов реализации.
Наиболее распространённые Polling/Longpolling. Тоже самое можно реализовать на Websockets или Server-Sent Events.
Краткий разбор всех трех способов (англ.) https://codeburst.io/polling-vs-sse-vs-websocket-how-to-choose-the-right-one-1859e4e13bd9

Ну и по названиям технологий, вы легко нагуглите подробные инструкции по реализации под ваши нужды.